# Rails 3.1 app can't connect with config.cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having a very odd issue in my rails 3.1 app where the app starts without error, but then I can't connect to it when I have `config.cache_classes = true`.

I have an existing app that i am upgrading from 3.0.10 to 3.1.5, although I'm not 100% convinced that is what's causing the issue.  I did make a few other changes to Gems before deploying, which I shouldn't have done, but everything was working fine in dev, so I wasn't concerned.

I've narrowed the issue down to cache_classes, after being completely confused for a day.  The issue is that there are zero errors, so I really don't know where to go with this.

*EDIT*
One hint as well. When I try to kill the rails server with cntrl-c it gives the "sinatra has ended his set" thing, but then it restarts itself.  I can only kill it with a kill -9.  It's fine with `config.cache_class = false`.

Here is my gem listing...

Gems included by the bundle:

```
* RedCloth (4.2.9)
* actionmailer (3.1.5)
* actionpack (3.1.5)
* activemodel (3.1.5)
* activerecord (3.1.5)
* activerecord-import (0.2.9)
* activeresource (3.1.5)
* activesupport (3.1.5)
* acts_as_reportable (1.1.1)
* addressable (2.2.6)
* ancestry (1.2.4)
* arel (2.2.3)
* aws-sdk (1.3.8)
* bbenezech-nested_form (0.0.6)
* bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
* bootstrap-sass (2.0.3.1)
* builder (3.0.0)
* bundler (1.0.15)
* cancan (1.6.5)
* chronic (0.6.5)
* cocaine (0.2.1)
* coffee-rails (3.1.1)
* coffee-script (2.2.0)
* coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
* color (1.4.1)
* css_parser (1.2.6)
* daemons (1.1.4)
* date_validator (0.6.2)
* devise (1.4.9)
* diff-lcs (1.1.3)
* em-websocket (0.3.6)
* erubis (2.7.0)
* eventmachine (0.12.10)
* execjs (1.4.0)
* faker (0.3.1)
* faraday (0.6.1)
* fastercsv (1.5.4)
* formtastic (1.2.4)
* geokit (1.6.5)
* geokit-rails3 (0.1.5)
* god (0.11.0)
* haml (3.1.6)
* has_scope (0.5.1)
* hashie (1.2.0)
* hike (1.2.1)
* hoe (2.12.4)
* hpricot (0.8.6)
* httparty (0.8.1)
* i18n (0.6.0)
* inherited_resources (1.2.2)
* jquery-rails (1.0.17)
* jquery-ui-rails (0.2.2)
* json (1.5.4)
* kaminari (0.13.0)
* mail (2.3.3)
* mailfactory (1.4.0)
* mime-types (1.18)
* mini_fb (1.1.7)
* multi_json (1.0.3)
* multi_xml (0.2.2)
* multipart-post (1.1.3)
* mysql (2.8.1)
* nokogiri (1.5.0)
* oa-core (0.2.5)
* oa-oauth (0.2.5)
* oauth (0.4.5)
* oauth2 (0.4.1)
* orm_adapter (0.0.7)
* paperclip (2.7.0)
* pdf-writer (1.1.8)
* polyglot (0.3.3)
* rack (1.3.6)
* rack-cache (1.2)
* rack-mount (0.8.3)
* rack-pjax (0.5.9)
* rack-ssl (1.3.2)
* rack-test (0.6.1)
* rails (3.1.5)
* rails-dev-boost (0.1.1 a995f0a)
* rails_admin (0.0.3)
* rails_autolink (1.0.9)
* railties (3.1.5)
* rake (0.8.7)
* rdoc (3.12)
* redis (2.2.2)
* redis-namespace (1.0.3)
* remotipart (1.0.2)
* responders (0.6.5)
* resque (1.17.1)
* resque-async-method (1.0.0)
* resque-async_deliver (1.2.0)
* resque-retry (0.1.0)
* resque-scheduler (1.9.9)
* rest-client (1.6.7)
* roadie (1.1.3)
* rspec (2.8.0)
* rspec-core (2.8.0)
* rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
* rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
* rspec-rails (2.8.1)
* rubyzip (0.9.5)
* rufus-scheduler (2.0.12)
* ruport (1.6.3)
* ruport-util (0.14.0)
* sass (3.1.19)
* sass-rails (3.1.6)
* simple_enum (1.3.2)
* sinatra (1.2.7)
* sprockets (2.0.4)
* thor (0.14.6)
* tilt (1.3.3)
* transaction-simple (1.4.0)
* treetop (1.4.10)
* tzinfo (0.3.33)
* uglifier (1.2.4)
* uuidtools (2.1.2)
* vegas (0.1.8)
* warden (1.0.6)
* webrat (0.7.1)
* whenever (0.7.0)
* will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
```

Any ideas?  I can get the app to run in production, but it's slow w/ config.cache_class = false

Comment: when you say "I can't connect to it when I have config.cache_classes = true.". what do you mean I can't connect to it? connecting via broswer? If yes, then does it work in `rails console`?

Comment: @Gaurish Adding to the weirdness. running `rails console` actually starts the web server. When I set `cache_classes = false`, and run the console, it starts fine. ??

Comment: It seems like the problem might actually have to do with Sinatra given that message. Do you mean to have Sinatra included in your app? And what's in the log files from boot up and when you try and connect?

Comment: I am not purposefully including Sinatra in the app. It's not in my Gemfile. Another gem must be using it?

Comment: My log file is showing lines like this: `Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method User.page.`  There's like 10 of them...each with a different model name, but not every model.  I've grepped for :page, but don't see it in my app/ or config/.

Comment: So, I think I've narrowed it down further to the fact that with `cache_classes = true` Sinatra loads up when you start the rails server.  And when it's set to `false` it doesn't.  Any ideas why? I don't want it included or starting up.  I'm trying to pull gems, in hopes of figuring out why it's loading.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening but maybe you can try to debug it step-by-step using `ruby-debug`?